# Add class name before method call on every additional for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop

How can I add `next.` on every additional loop?

First loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<=index; i++){
    retValue = getValue();
}
```

Second loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<=index; i++){

    retValue = next.getValue();
```

Third loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<=index; i++){

    retValue = next.next.getValue();
}
```

and so on.

Comment: Use temporary variables? This is Java, not JavaScript. Learn the difference and tag your questions correctly.

Comment: It seems like you are not asking for what you want to achieve, but wrongly assume a solution for your problem, that if it is impossible will not solve your problem.
Also you are not adding a class name in your code example, but a variable name.

Comment: Can you show a bit of the surrounding code to give some context?

Answer (score 1):

## How to do what you want

You can use a temporary variable to hold the value (in my example it has the type T)

```
T temp = this;
for(int i=0; i<=index; i++){
    retValue = this.getValue();
    temp = temp.next;
}
```

## Using iterators

If you make an iterator which returns the next values as above, then you can iterate over the items like this:

```
for (T item : getIterator) {
    retValue = item.getValue();
}
```